# When changing index.php to index.html i get a error in ionic

Tags: php, html, ionic-framework

Recently I found a way to take php and put it directly into ionic by changing the extension to .php and in the routes change the extension to .php so it only works on a installed server I thought it would work and it show the php on the mobile device so I thought that I could change index.html to index.php and I get a error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\xampp2\htdocs\myApp\www\index.html'
```

So is there a way to change index.html to index.php

Comment: Why do you want to use the php file?

Comment: Because i thought it would work

Comment: No, i mean the purpose, why?

Comment: so i did not have to go though a bunch of trouble with angularjs to put php there @SatejS

Comment: I don't understand.What exactly is it that you want to achieve with a PHP file, that Angular/HTML isn't doing.

Comment: i did'nt know any other way to do it

Comment: @Satej S Could you move the discussion to chat?

Answer (score 2):

Your mobile device isn't running PHP, PHP is a server-side language and Ionic is used to build client-side apps using Javascript. Theoretically you could build an app in Ionic with PHP interspersed and deploy it to a LAMP server and it would run in a web browser but that kind of defeats the purpose of Ionic/hybrid app architecture and I would not recommend it.

Comment: how would i fix the issue

Comment: what are you trying to do with PHP? paste in your `index.php` file